# MySQL Variables and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having an issue with a PDO query that is using MySQL variables. I've executed this query within MySQL workbench, as well as directly from what is being processed and stored via the MySQL general log and get results. When it is ran via PDO, my rowCount() comes back with 0.

I've checked error logs and try / catch on PDOException, but nothing is there. I've also dug around a bit on using MySQL vars with PDO, but from what I've found there shouldn't be any issues.

Here is the query:

```
$mobile_query = $online_link->prepare('SELECT
T.full_date,
T.login_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        M.Process_Date as full_date,
        M.Nbr_Success_Sigon,
        @dup := CASE WHEN @prev_login <> M.Nbr_Success_Sigon THEN 1 ELSE (@dup+1) END AS reset,
        @num_logins := (M.Nbr_Success_Sigon - @prev_login) as login_count,
        @prev_login := M.Nbr_Success_Sigon
    FROM mobile_tran M
    WHERE
        M.CIS_No = :cis AND
        M.Process_Date  >= :start_date + INTERVAL -' . $date_interval . ' DAY AND
        M.Process_Date  < :start_date
)as T
WHERE T.reset = 1 AND T.login_count > 0');

try {
  $mobile_query->execute(array(':cis'=>$cis, ':start_date'=>$start_date));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  $logger->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

The data set is a rolling count of logins with one entry per day. I only want to return days in which the count has changed.

For example:

```
07-01 - 0
07-02 - 0
07-03 - 1 (<- I want to return this record)
07-04 - 1
07-05 - 3 (<- I want to return this record)
```

Is there some kind of odd restriction with PDO that I am missing when it comes to using MySQL variables?

Comment: It's likely not the SQL variables. PDO doesn't support `rowCount` for SELECT queries per default (because support among other drivers is spotty). There's [::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930) however. Or did the query really return nothing when *fetching* results?

Comment: have you tried to pass this variable '$date_interval' to query as named parameter from array

Comment: I have tried fetching data from the query as well. Nothing. The $date_interval call isn't the problem as I am using the same WHERE statement in other queries that don't involve the MySQL vars. They work fine. If I were to remove all the MySQL vars and just return Process_Date and the Nbr_Success_Sigons, I do return data. This is what leads me to believe it has something to do with the vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was an issue, but I was able to get data by setting the variables to default values in a previous query.

```
  $var_query = $online_link->query('SET @dump = 0, @num_logins = 0, @prev_login = 0');
```

As long as that was executed before the main query, all worked as it should.